# Sent Strict-Transport-Security header, but Chrome is still requesting via http

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, php-7, hsts

I'm running a new site on Google App Engine with a custom domain and I want to require all traffic to come through via https.

I created a test script at http://rublonde.com/tmp:

```
<?
header("Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=180; includeSubdomains");
print $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'];
```

(The content of the site doesn't really match the domain name, I'm just temporarily using this domain as a custom domain so I can get the HTTPS header thing working.)

In Google App Engine, the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` will be either `http` or `https`. On the first load of this page, I assumed it would get the the HSTS header and then on subsequent loads of the page, Chrome should automatically be requesting the page via https.

Am I misunderstanding how HSTS works? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I realized that HSTS headers are ignored when sent over an http connection (I think because they need to be associated with a valid certificate that comes with the https connection).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#HSTS_mechanism_overview

> A server implements an HSTS policy by supplying a header over an HTTPS
>   connection (HSTS headers over HTTP are ignored).

Comment: It’s nothing to do with being associated with a certificate - it’s a security feature. HTTP requests can be changed in transit and if you could add HSTS to a site that doesn’t support HTTPS then you could DoS that site for a long time for any users who’s traffic is being intercepted. Only using it when it’s been sent over a valid HTTPS connection prevents this from happening.